# WP7 and Silverlight-> Does WiFi get disconnected when running your app under a locked screen and when idle is disabled?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

My app is a GPS tracker and I want to keep it running while the screen is locked or idle.
In order to do this I do the following:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

...

PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
    IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = 
    IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

This works ok, but It seems that the WiFi gets disconnected after a while. Is this normal? Is there a way to keep it alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt any way of preventing it from disconnecting when the screen locks. Its one of the behaviors of the os that isnt exposed to developers.

Answer (score 0):

I tested that out on my WP7 device and the WiFi does get disconnected if the user locks the screen manually.

Comment: Thanks for testing that but I would like to know if there is a way of preventing that.